# Storing text as an arraylist from JTextArea

Tags: java, arraylist, actionlistener, actionevent

I need to create a program to store all words in an array list. Then check the user input from the textfield to see if it starts with anything other than numbers and punctuation. Otherwise it will need to display an error and prvent the string to be added to the arraylist and display an appropriate error.

https://pastebin.com/8UwDm4nE

Heres the ActionEvent listener that contins the code to check that. Im not really sure how to get it working.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        String str = tf.getText(); // MUST BE STORED ON AN ARRAY LIST
        ta.append(str + "\n"); // Append the text on new line each

        if(str.startsWith(String.valueOf(nums))) { // Check input for a number at the start
            error.setText("Error: Word starts a number. Please try again!");
            error.setForeground(Color.RED);
            ta.append("");
        } else if (str.startsWith(String.valueOf(punct))) { // Check if input contains a punctuation at the start
            error.setText("Error: Word starts with an illegal character. Please try again!");
            error.setForeground(Color.RED);
            ta.append("");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to rephrase your problem a bit as clarification, please correct me if I'm misunderstanding.

You have a text field and a text area. You want a user to type a word into the text field and submit it. If that word starts with a number or punctuation, then indicate an error to the user. Otherwise, add it to the text area (on a new line) and the inner ArrayList.

To solve this problem, there are a couple things you'll need:

1. An `ArrayList<String>` that is a class member variable where you can store your words
2. An event handler that handles the button click.

The event handler should:

1. Parse the string from the text field (using `getText()`, as you already are).
2. Do the error checks you're already doing.
3. If neither of the error conditions are hit (so add an `else` clause for this), add the word to the text area (which you're already doing) and add it to the ArrayList.

Hopefully this helps you get a clearer idea of how to approach the problem. If not, please post a code sample of what you tried and what error you're specifically running into.

EDIT: 
Here is some pseudocode for your if-else error-handling block of code, assuming you declare a new `ArrayList` to hold your words as a class member:

```
// as class member variable
List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<>();

// word handler code
if (str starts with a number) {
    // handle error
} else if (str starts with punctuation) {
    // handle error
} else {
    ta.append(str + "\n");
    wordList.add(str);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I believe you are spot on. The problem that I am currently facing is how to store the text into the array list but append it to the JTextArea as well. I am unsure how to store each number into an array and check if any of those numbers are at the start of the user input. I am using the .StartsWith function to check that but unsure how to use the array of numbers/punctuation with this function.

Comment: Edited my answer to show some pseudocode that should solve your first problem: " how to store the text into the array list but append it to the JTextArea as well".

As a follow-up to your second problem, let's look at what you're defining as a **valid word**, and what might make it **invalid**. For example, are there only certain numbers/punctuation symbols that would make it invalid, or is it anything that is not a letter?

Comment: So the input must start with a letter e.g. "hello". If the text is found to have a digit at the beginning it will have to display an error and skip appending to the array list. I have done the checks by using an if statement that checks if the first index or digit is a number.